# Chronicle Map UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, chronicle, unsupported-class-version, chronicle-map

I'm just trying out ChronicleMap and have run into an issue immediately, an "UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0".

I'm using Java 7... should I interpret this error to mean that Chronicle Map is compiled under Java 8?  Do I need to download the source code and compile under Java 7 to fix this (would this even work)?

Comment: As of 2018, the best solution would be to upgrade to Java 8 ... or Java 11.  Java 7 has been EOL for a long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry:

ChronicleMap 1.0.2 requires Java 8; we realize this is causing problems so are looking to release ChronicleMap 2.0.0a (as an alpha release) in the next few days, which will work on Java 7:

```xml
<groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
<artifactId>chronicle-map</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0a</version>
```

Yes, if you were to download the source code and compile under Java 7 it will work, but you will have to build all the snapshot artifacts that it uses, or download them from:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Snapshot Repository</id>
        <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. Looking  forward to the new release.

Comment: Thanks.  I spent a couple hours today trying to make it work under Java 7, so far unsuccessfully.  Count me among those eagerly awaiting the 2.0 release!  :)

Answer (score 1):

We have just released Chronicle Map 2.0.0a, this release works on java 1.7 ( unlike the previous version which required java 1.8 ). Data written and read using Chronicle Map 2.0.0a is not backwards compatible with the previous version of Chronicle Map. Chronicle Map 2.0.0a introduces custom serialisation. This version is an alpha release and as such we recommend you don’t use it in production.